# Finding the Conditional Mutual Information between 3 RVs

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

> A six-sided fair die is rolled. Obtain the mutual information between the random variable $X$ and the random variables $Y$ and $Z$, where:
>
> - $X$: number of on the front face (side facing you)
> - $Y$: number of on the top face
> - $Z$: number of on the bottom face

To answer this question, should I be finding the mutual information between $X$ and ($Y$ given $Z$)?

$I(X; Y|Z) = H(X|Z) - H(X|Y,Z)$

Would the fact that the front face can be 1 of 6 options, and then top face would be 1 of 4 options adjacent to this front face, and then given this top face, we know with certainty what the bottom face is mean that $H(X|Y,Z) = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks for $I(X;Y,Z)$ (if I understand it correctly).

From the chain rule it follows
$$
I(X;Y,Z) = I(X;Y|Z) + I(X;Z).
$$
Now, since knowledge of $Y$ implies knowledge of $Z$ and vice versa, it follows that 
$$
\begin{align}
I(X;Y|Z)&=H(X|Z)-H(X|Y,Z)\\
&=H(X|Z)-H(X|Z)\\
&=0,
\end{align}
$$ 
that is, given the value of $Z$, no (further) information is gained about $X$ when $Y$ is observed. I leave it to you the computation of $I(X;Z)$.

Comment: You say that "given the value of $Z$, no (further) information is gained about $X$ when $Y$ is observed". But given the value of $Z$ (bottom face), we then know that $X$ could be 1 of 4 faces. Then, when $Y$ is observed there is only one possible face that $X$ could be?

Comment: @KOB if you know $Z$ you have some information about $X$ (you known it can be one of $4$ faces). However, knowledge of $Z$ also implies knowledge of $Y$, hence, the actual "observation" of $Y$ (given $Z$) does not offer any additional information to what you already know about $X$.

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense. Just the last thing I am not quite undertanding is how and why you thought the answer would be in the form of $I(X;Y,Z)$ and not $I(X;Y|Z)$?

Comment: @KOB Just how I interpret the question. I would expect something like "Obtain the mutual information between the random variable X and the random variables Y *conditioned (or given)* Z" if it was asking for $I(X;Y|Z)$.